# "Unknown column in 'where clause'" when executing stored procedure from python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to create and execute a stored procedure in mysql using python.

the table I read from looks like this:

[image: orbital_data]

this is command for creating the proc, which runs fine:

```py
new_conn = engine.raw_connection()
    mycursor = new_conn.cursor()
 mycursor.execute('''CREATE PROCEDURE getAvgPerCity 
                            (
                               IN city VARCHAR(64),
                                IN des_table VARCHAR(255)
                            ) 
                            BEGIN 
                            SET @Sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',des_table,'(location,avg_value,insert_time)
                            select location,avg_per_city, NOW() AS insert_time from
                            (
                             select location,avg(total) as avg_per_city from 
                               (
                            select location,date(risetime) as dt_day,count(*) as total
                            from 
                            orbital_data
                            
                            group by location,dt_day
                            ) as q1 
          
                            group by location) as q2
                             WHERE location = ',city,';');
                             
                            PREPARE stmt FROM @Sql;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


                            END  ''')
```

then, I call the procedure:

```py
args = ['Haifa', 'city_stats_Haifa']
mycursor.callproc('getAvgPerCity', args)
```

Then the code crashes with the following error:

<MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Haifa' in 'where clause'")>

All column names are the original names, no aliases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the final query that is run is being executed like this
where location = Haifa.
the value must be quoted

Comment: Likely the problem is that the value of city is not enclosed in single quotes. The generated SQL is probably `WHERE location = Haifa` . MySQL is seeing `Haifa` as an identifier (a column name) and not a string literal. Best practice would be to make that a bind placeholder, so SQL text would be `WHERE location = ?` and supply a value for the placeholder in the EXECUTE.  if we are going to include the value as part of the SQL text, it must be properly escaped (to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerability) and must be enclosed in single quotes, so the generated SQL text `WHERE location = 'Haifa'`

Comment: I need to create the procedure prior calling it with the parameters. How do I make sure I generate location = 'Haifa'?

Comment: How do I execute an existing procedure with a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double quotes around city name

```
new_conn = engine.raw_connection()
mycursor = new_conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute('''CREATE PROCEDURE getAvgPerCity 
                            (
                               IN city VARCHAR(64),
                                IN des_table VARCHAR(255)
                            ) 
                            BEGIN 
                            SET @Sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `',des_table,'`(location,avg_value,insert_time)
                            select location,avg_per_city, NOW() AS insert_time from
                            (
                             select location,avg(total) as avg_per_city from 
                               (
                            select location,date(risetime) as dt_day,count(*) as total
                            from 
                            orbital_data
                            
                            group by location,dt_day
                            ) as q1 
          
                            group by location) as q2
                             WHERE location = "',city,'";');
                             
                            PREPARE stmt FROM @Sql;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


                            END  ''')
```

If the city name is not checked this could be entry point for sql injection so you can use [prepare statemnts with oarameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you're missing quotes around the city in the SQL. But rather than adding quotes, you should make the statement take a parameter, to avoid SQL-injection.

```
new_conn = engine.raw_connection()
mycursor = new_conn.cursor()
mycursor.execute('''
    CREATE PROCEDURE getAvgPerCity 
    (
        IN city VARCHAR(64),
        IN des_table VARCHAR(255)
    ) 
    BEGIN
        SET @city = city;
        SET @Sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `',des_table,'` (location,avg_value,insert_time)
                           select location,avg_per_city, NOW() AS insert_time from (
                               select location,avg(total) as avg_per_city from (
                                   select location,date(risetime) as dt_day,count(*) as total
                                   from orbital_data
                                   group by location,dt_day
                               ) as q1 
                               group by location) as q2
                               WHERE location = ?;');
                             
        PREPARE stmt FROM @Sql;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @city;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END  ''')
```

Unfortunately, you can't use a placeholder for the table name. The best you can do is put backticks around it, in case it contains special characters.